# How to Iterate overdivs with same id and change the color using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code

```
$("#diagonal").each(function (i) {
  $("#diagonal").css("background","green"); //Change color of the div        
});
```

I want to all divs with id `#diagonal` change colors.

This method dont work:

```
<div class="col span_1_of_12">
  <div id="diagonal">   
    <!-- 1 of 12 -->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col span_1_of_12">
  <!-- 2 of 12 -->
</div>
<div class="col span_1_of_12">
  <div id="diagonal">   
    <!-- 1 of 12 -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Use reference: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: It is invalid html to have multiple elements with same id on a page. Only the first element `diagonal` will be updated, use classes instead.

Comment: Your request is flawed from the start; no elements can share the same `id` attribute. Use classes to group elements, exactly as you are for the `span_1_of_12` elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/a9h3n3Lq/

```js
$( ".diagonal" ).each(function( i ) {
    $(this).css("background","green"); //Change color of the div


  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col span_1_of_12">
    <div class="diagonal">

    1 of 12
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_12">
    2 of 12
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_12">
    <div class="diagonal">

    1 of 12
    </div>
    </div>
```

Id should be unique, instead please use class for similar elements.